# Are QDM and QDR the same as 'inbound' and 'outbound' courses?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, navigation, terminology, radio-navigation

I'm about to take my last test to join an airline: the simulator. I've been told they ask to perform some QDR/QDM interceptions, as well as radial ones.

About QDM/QDR:

- QDM: Magnetic course from the aircraft towards the station.
- QDR: Magnetic course from the station to the aircraft.

I guess we all may agree with that. But:

1. Could we always take QDM as an inbound course? E.g. the aircraft is at 'radial' 180 and the examiner tells me: "Intercept QDM 320". That would be the same as saying "intercept the inbound course 320", right?
2. The opposite for QDR. Shall I take it as always an OUTBOUND course?

Probably QDM/QDR is used for NDBs and for practical uses they cannot speak about a radial, but anyways I'd like to know if my points are correct.

Answer (score 5):

- QDM is the magnetic bearing **to** the station.
- QDR is the magnetic bearing **from** the station.

Not to be confused with *course*, which is the direction in which the aircraft is moving but has nothing to do with the heading of the aircraft. Imagine having a heading of 270 but a course of 090. That means there is so much headwind that you are moving backwards.

Radials are not the same since a radial is always a magnetic bearing **from** the station. Therefore flying the radial 180 both inbound and outbound will both give you a position south of the station.

This is not the case with QDM and QDR.

- Flying a QDM 180 will give you a position north of the station and flying 180 (without taking the wind into account) towards the station.
- Flying a QDR 180 will give you a position south of the station and flying 180 (without taking the wind into account) away from the station.

Let's imagine a VOR and an NDB located on top of each other and there is no wind factor:

- Flying QDM 180 will put you on radial 000 with a heading of 180.
- Flying QDR 180 will put you on radial 180 with a heading of 180.
- Flying radial 180 inbound will put you on QDM 000 with a heading of 000.
- Flying radial 180 outbound will put you on QDR 180 with a heading of 180.

Long story short, radials are visualised in relation to the beacon. QDM/QDR are magnetic bearings visualised in relation to the plane's nose.